# Method doesn't work

Tags: java

For my assignment, I have to use methods to find the number of patterns in an array. The pattern is counted when the sum of adjacent numbers in an array is more than 7.

I have to use 2 methods, 1 being insertNumbers to create an array and another being computePattern to count the patterns.

However, the pattern printed out doesn't match the array printed out. Here is the code.

As this is an assignment, I would rather not get answers but answers on which part of my code is wrong, and how do I fix it.

EDIT: Here is a sample output.

Sample output #1:  Array:  2  7  2  3  1  5  7  4  3  6

Number of patterns: 3

```
public static int[] insertNumbers()
{
    //Declaring the array.
    int randomArray[] = new int[10];

    //Setting random numbers into the array.
    for (int k = 0;k < randomArray.length;k++)
    {
        int i = (int)((Math.random()*9)+1);
        randomArray[k] = i;
    }

    //Returning array into other methods.
    return randomArray;
}

public static int computePattern()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int pattern = 0;
    int[] randomArray = insertNumbers();
    //Computing the number of patterns.
    for (;a<=8 && b<=9;)
    {
        if (randomArray[a] + randomArray[b]>7)
        {
            pattern++;            
        }      
        a+=2;
        b+=2;
    }
    return pattern;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int pattern = computePattern();
    int[] randomArray = insertNumbers();

    //Printing out the contents of the array.
    System.out.print("Array : " );
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(+randomArray[i] +" ");
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    //Printing out the number of patterns.
    System.out.println("Number of patterns: "+pattern);
}
```

Comment: could you include an `input`, `actuall output` and `expected output`? This would make it a little bit easier to understand your assigment just by checking what is and should happen.

Comment: `a+=2; b+=2;` Why are you adding 2? You're skipping potential values.

Comment: @KevinEsche - As far as I understand the code, it has no `input` and the output is an array of ten random numbers (and number of detected patterns). Best that could be provided is an example for testing the pattern identification, but that doesn't seem to be the problem (yet).

Comment: @Manu Sorry, I didn't exactly clarify the adjacent numbers part. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are computing pattern for a different array, and in `main` you are printing different array (you are calling `insertNumbers` twice basically). See here:

```
    int pattern = computePattern(); // First time computePatter generates one array
    int[] randomArray = insertNumbers(); // Another array is generated here
```

Also, doesn't seem your pattern counting is correct. Hint: does it compare elements with indexes 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the compute pattern part this way

{

```
    int a;
    int pattern = 0;
    int[] randomArray = insertNumbers();
    //Computing the number of patterns.
    for (a=1;a<9;a++)
    {
        if (randomArray[a] + randomArray[a-1]>7)
        {
            pattern++;            
        }      

    }
    return pattern;
}
```

And you definitely calling insertNumbers Twice. You should call it once in main and send that array to computePattern.

```
int[] randomArray = insertNumbers();
int pattern = computePattern(randomArray);
```

Comment: Didn't you read the last sentence *"As this is an assignment, I would rather not get answers but answers on which part of my code is wrong, and how do I fix it."*

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your `main` function

```
int[] randomArray = insertNumbers();
```

You are calling the function `insertNumbers` again after computing the pattern.